# Make a XYZ data from a corresponding distributed point cloud by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have a XYZ point cloud which resemble a surface. However, for some post processing it should get modified. The input files have the same XY with an exact interval value. If we put them in a columnar array they look like this:

```
0 0 Z1
1 0 Z2
2 0 Z3
0 1 Z4
1 1 Z5
.
.
.
2 2 Z9
```

However, after some processes, the coordination of atoms change. For example, something like this:

```
0.1  -0.18 Z'1
0.04  0.4  Z'2
...
```

I want to make a corresponding point cloud from this distorted XYZ, but with a XY data as the original one so it can be analyzed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpolate using `griddata`

```
iz = griddata( xnew, ynew, Zprime, oldx, oldy );
```

Where

```
xold = [0 1 2 0 1 ...
yold = [0 0 0 1 1 ...   
xnew = [0.1 0.04 ...
ynew = [-0.18 0.4 ...
```